# Ordering characters by longer character sequence (to order peptides by protein sequence)

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Im working with proteome data and would like to show the peptide expression according to the actual protein sequence. Currently they are ordered according to their usage in quantification (= random).
I suppose you can do this using regular expressions / stringr&rebus (preferably) but I couldnt figure out how.

Here is a data example, many thanks for your help!

```
peptides <- data.frame(peptide = c(1,2,3,4),
                   sequence = c("PRDPDPASRTH", "MTLGRRLACLF", "RRARPHAWP", "APNFVMSAAH"),
                   log2quant = c(21, 12, 17, 18))

protein_sequence <- c("MTLGRRLACLFLACVLPALLLGGTALASEIVGGRRARPHAWPFMVSLQLRGGHFCGATLIAPNFVMSAAHCVANVNVRAVRVVLGAHNLSRREPTRQVFAVQRIFENGYDPVNLLNDIVILQLNGSATINANVQVAQLPAQGRRLGNGVQCLAMGWGLLGRNRGIASVLQELNVTVVTSLCRRSNVCTLVRGRQAGVCFGDSGSPLVCNGLIHGIASFVRGGCASGLYPDAFAPVAQFVNWIDSIIQRSEDNPCPHPRDPDPASRTH")


expected_result <- data.frame(peptide = c(1,2,3,4),
                   sequence = c("PRDPDPASRTH", "MTLGRRLACLF", "RRARPHAWP", "APNFVMSAAH"),
                   log2quant = c(21, 12, 17, 18),
                   order = c(4, 1, 2, 3))
```

The sequence I copy/pasted from Uniprot (its the ELANE protein). Rest of the data comes from MassSpec results.
Would be great to find a solution for this, many thanks!

Comment: You should add more description about how that input becomes the vector output.  Do not assume that all of your readers are very familiar with biochemistry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str_locate` from `stringr` to get the location of start (or end) of the pattern in the string `protein_sequence` and use `rank` to get it's order.

```
peptides$order <- rank(stringr::str_locate(protein_sequence,peptides$sequence)[, 1])

peptides
#  peptide    sequence log2quant order
#1       1 PRDPDPASRTH        21     4
#2       2 MTLGRRLACLF        12     1
#3       3   RRARPHAWP        17     2
#4       4  APNFVMSAAH        18     3
```

Make sure that `peptides$sequence` is character and not `factor` before using it in `str_locate`.